# lower_bound function not working properly?

Tags: c++

I am using lower_bound to search for element greater than or equal to key in the range [back,end) of a vector which may contain decreasing elements in the given range. So ,I also have to use the greater() functor. The value returned should be the last element itself(for the given range), but the function returns 0. Why?

```cpp
vector<int>v={1,2,3,4,5};
int i=3;
cout<<*lower_bound(next(v.begin(),i+1),v.end(),v[i],greater<int>());
```

expected output : 5

if i remove the greater() code, it works fine.

Comment: What is going on with the `next()` part? Are you trying to scan from offset 4? That's the last element in the array.

Comment: @tadman The OP is trying to go backwards.

Comment: @tadman there is some more code which makes 'i' iterate towards zero while everything towards right of 'i' becomes decreasing. I omitted that part because I was just concerned with this particular behavior sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am using lower_bound to search for element greater than or equal to key in the range [back,end) of a vector which may contain decreasing elements in the given range. So ,I also have to use the greater() functor.
>
> ```
> vector<int>v={1,2,3,4,5};
> ```

`std::lower_bound` requires that the input range is sorted according to the comparison object argument. Your vector is not sorted with the `std::greater`. If it was, then the greatest value would be first.

If your vector is sorted such that least value is first, then you must use `std::less` (which is the default, so does not need to be specified explicitly).

---

That said, `next(v.begin(),3+1)` is an iterator to the last element of the array, so the range `[next(v.begin(),3+1), v.end()[` contains exactly one element, whose value is 5. So this range of a single element is in fact sorted according to all possible comparison functions, so using `std::greater` is technically not a problem.

So, `std::lower_bound` returns the iterator to the first value that does not satisfy the comparison (i.e. is not less than when using `std::less` or is not greater than when using `std::greater`). Otherwise it returns iterator to the end of the range, which in your case is one past the last element of the array.

You've given v[3] i.e the value 4 as the compared value. The range that contains the value 5 does not contain any elements that are not greater than 4, and therefore `std::lower_bound` returns the iterator to the end of the range. You indirect through this iterator, and the behaviour of the program is undefined.

If you don't use `std::greater` i.e. you implicitly use `std::less`, then the range that contains value 5 does contain an element that is not less than 4. Namely the one element whose value is 5. Thus `std::lower_bound` returns iterator to that element, and indirection through that iterator produces the value 5.

---

Comment: Hey what do i use if i need to find an element which is equal to or greater than a given key in a decreasing array? For an increasing array this can be done by lower_bound (implicit comparator) therefore i had mistakenly assumed that just using std::greater with lower_bound will do the trick (being grossly wrong with the basic concepts!).

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to use the reference to `std::greater`.

The `std::lower_bound` function uses a comparison operator to work out whether the element you're searching for is greater than or lower than the elements in the collection. The function presumes that the comparison operator is for less-than, i.e. `std::less`, and if you provide `std::greater` instead, the algorithm will get confused and evaluate items in reverse order.

Comment: Presumably reverse iterators can help here